# Enhance canvas performance when using clearRect and drawImage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a canvas game, and I was wondering how do I draw hundreds of images without noticeable performance? I read to make an 'off-screen' canvas to do some of the works, so I added that. But It doesn't seem to improve performance.

Here is the performance chart:

[image: Chart]

Here is some pseudo code:

```
function tick(){
    // Run updates to update positions, rotations, scales, etc.
    update();
    // Run render
    render();
}

function render(){
    bufferContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gameobjects.forEach(item => {
        bufferContext.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, cx, cy, width, height);
    });

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(bufferCanvas, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    tick();
});
```

Here is an example of many characters running across this screen (Small portion of the canvas. It also runs smoother outside of the gif)

[image: Characters]

What could I do to enhance the performance of `clearRect` and `drawImage`?

Entry point:
https://github.com/TheColorRed/blueberry/blob/master/src/main.ts

The Engine Core:
https://github.com/TheColorRed/blueberry/blob/master/src/core/Engine.ts

The Rederer:
https://github.com/TheColorRed/blueberry/blob/master/src/core/Stage.ts

Comment: Html5 Canvas already buffers itself so buffering the *entire canvas* is not necessary or desireable. The `context.drawImage` command is a black-box & is fairly close to the metal so there's no enhancing its performance directly. Instead (if possible), reduce the number of `drawImage` calls. So if a set of gameobjects are *unchanging relative to each other* (even temporarily for a few ticks) then you can cache that set of gameobjects to another canvas and drawImage that bigger combined set to the display canvas.

Comment: Important information is required to make sense of the timing data. Number of drawImage calls made, resolution of canvas  & img you are drawing, how you call tick? Also looks like you are using Chrome.  Chrome does not like forEach, it is 2-3 times slower than a for or while loop.

Comment: I have been testing with one spritesheet image that I display a section of for a characters running animation. I then also don't draw the item if it is not in view of the canvas. which I assume would help optimize it. I have had about 500 - 600 different items on the canvas each having a movement (see attached gif). I also start the tick with a window load event, which I have added to the code.

Comment: Some of those pixels must be getting drawn 5 or more times per frame. Perhaps a speedup from some kind of hidden surface removal would be possible.